# Chrome MTurk Extension Javascript Fetch Response.status=200 for accept_project_task_url but HIT is not Queued

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, fetch-api, mturk

I have an extension that sends accept_project_task_url, via fetch API, in which the response.status=200. That is supposed to mean success but that hit is not queued. Why is 200 being returned when the accept hit fails? Is there something else I need to do to get the HIT queued? TIA.

What may or may not mean anything, in that case the response.text() is HTML rather than json.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but you already asked the same question two days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74025601/mturk-chrome-extension-fetch-response-status-200-for-accept-project-task-url-but Asking a question again, because you didn't get an answer the first time, is probably not a good idea. Flagging your question as a duplicate would require the original question to be answered first: "I am flagging to report this question as... a duplicate. This question has been asked before and already has an answer."

Comment: Sorry but I was having problems the other day. The post never showed up and I got an error saying there was maintenance going on. I did not intentionally double post. It was not until this post that the other one started to show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone else that may run into this problem, it turns out that when a HIT is no longer available the return status may still be 200. However, in that case it returns an HTML page of MTurk HITs with the banner that says HITs of this type are no longer available. It is a bad situation but it is what it is.